# Characters added and wrong output during serialization with Json.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json

JSON.NET seems to serialize my code into what appear to be strings, instead of objects. Here's an example of what it returns:

```
  "{\"kvk_nummer\":11111111,\"onderneming\":\"berijf B.V.\",\"vestigingsplaats\":\"AMSTERDAM\",\"actief\":1}"
```

It also adds strange backslashes, I tried to get rid of them, but none of the answers I've found seemed to have helped. Here is the code that returns the string.

```
getregister r = new getregister
    {
    kvk_nummer = col1, //contains an 8 digit number
    onderneming = checkTotaal[col1], //contains a name
    vestigingsplaats = checkTotaal2[col1], //contains a location
    actief = 1 // bool that represents wether the company is active or not
    };
    yield return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
```

How can i get JSON.NET to output an object, instead of some JSON strings?

Comment: Sounds like double-serialization. I see you're doing it explicitly. Perhaps whatever's calling your code is *also* doing it?

Comment: I could not discover what could be, the class that i called does not appear to serialize on it's own, and the only time i told anything to serialize is via the return

Comment: "JSON.NET seems to serialize my code into what appear to be strings, instead of objects."...JSON is text, so yes that's exactly what it does. It's a data transmission or storage format. If you want to use it in some code for processing or manipulation or querying, then you have to de-serialise it back to an object again. And the backslashes aren't strange, they're escape characters because you can't have a double-quote inside a string literal, otherwise C# doesn't know where the string starts and ends.

Comment: Possibly as TJ Crowder says, some double-encoding is going on. That or you're just viewing the object through the Visual Studio debugger, and that's just how it displays it. It's unclear a) exactly what you're doing, and b) what exactly you want or need to do instead. I suspect this is only one snippet of code amongst some others...a bit of context would help us figure out how to help you.

Comment: I was aware that Visual Studio's debugger could cause issues, so i tried requesting it via Postman, with the same result. I can not apply filters to the request, and if i do it will return the same content as it did without the filter. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're confusing some stuff. Taken from [Serialization (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/)

> Serialization is the process of converting an object into a stream of bytes to store the object or transmit it to memory, a database, or a file. Its main purpose is to save the state of an object in order to be able to recreate it when needed. The reverse process is called deserialization.

When you serialize into JSON, you get a JSON representation of your object. Which is a string representation. Taken from the [JSON Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON):

> JavaScript Object Notation or JSON is an open-standard file format that uses human-readable text to transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs and array data types (or any other serializable value).

In short: your code is doing what you're asking it to do. As far as the slashes go: those are escape characters. If you want (JSON.NET to return) an object, return the object you're creating (`r`).

```
return new getregister
{
    kvk_nummer = col1, //contains an 8 digit number
    onderneming = checkTotaal[col1], //contains a name
    vestigingsplaats = checkTotaal2[col1], //contains a location
    actief = 1 // bool that represents wether the company is active or not
};
```

If you're looking for a way to have JSON.NET return an object, you should take a look into Deserializing it. Since that takes the string-representation (JSON) for your object, and turns it back into an actual object for you.

Comment: @Colgate_Man420 What is it you're actually trying to do? If you need to return an object from a method, just return the object. Oh, and take a look at my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try that. Stupid of me that i didn't try that before, i was under the impression that serialising would do that for me.